Quarkus Kafka autodetect Serialization/Deserialization with messaging objects from a shared module (instead of duplicating object sender/receiver)
I'm running through the Getting Started to Quarkus Messaging with Kafka.
I tried veering away from the instructions a little by putting my Quote response object in a shared java module. It took me a while to realize why the otherwise valid quote response was being prefixed by "Quote{..." -- The autodetection of serialization/deserialization didn't apply and the Quote.toString() method was being used instead.
So simple fix: follow the instructions by putting a copy of Quote in both the requester and processor modules. The build logs indicate the the detection and generation of the deserializer:

[io.quarkus.smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka.deployment.processor] Generating Jackson deserializer for type model.Quote

So yes, the doc mentions keeping it simple by duplicating Quote in both modules.
And yes, eventually I'd like to use Avro to manage my messaging shemas, but before doing that, I'd like to know if it's feasible (and desirable) to autodetect and generate Serializers/Deserializers for objects coming from 'common' modules outside of the project. This documentation seems indicate that it's done from the annotations... so 'no' for the most part.
The other option I see is manually creating the Serializer/Deserializer in the common module, though I'd hope I can generate this automagically.
Does anyone have enough experience with the Quarkus/Kafka/Jackson libraries to tell me where this auto-detection is happening and using what libs to generate the (de)serializers ? Is it possible to gen the (de)serializers in my 'common' jar ? And lastly, is this a waste of time and a bad idea ? If I don't have the time or env to set up a schema registry, are there better ways to do this other than  duplicating or shared module ?
Thanks in advance for your advice.
